# Mysql Join, check if user has / has no permission

Tags: php, mysql, join

Trying to do this with a single query, but want to get a list of all users who have permission to do x. This involves the users table and permissions table. But it looks like any joins I use doesnt care about the where statement (since the user will usually have another permission in the table)

```
SELECT DISTINCT `u`.*
FROM (`system_users` AS u)
JOIN `system_user_permissions` AS p ON `u`.`id` = `p`.`user`
WHERE `p`.`permission` != 2
AND `p`.`permission` != 3
```

I have about 3900 users, I should receive about 2000 users who are not tied to either permission id 2 or 3. But still get 3900 The problem is because the user may also be tied to permission 1,5,6... they still get put in the list after it groups them together.

Any suggestions?

---

Updated query, still no luck though. If I output "permission" for each one I don't get 2 or 3, the users listed still may have that permission there

```
SELECT DISTINCT `u`.*, `p`.`permission`
FROM (`system_users` AS u)
INNER JOIN `system_user_permissions` AS p ON `u`.`id` = `p`.`user`
WHERE `p`.`permission` NOT IN (2, 3)
```

---

**This did the trick:**

```
SELECT * FROM system_users AS u 
        WHERE NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT 1 FROM system_user_permissions AS p
            WHERE u.id = p.user
            AND p.permission IN (2,3)
)
```

Comment: write what kind of output you want from the query

Comment: I just need the list of users. Just joining to use the where functionality

Comment: Give us the sample output. As well as the table structure, if the tables aren't too large.

Comment: Also, try Ricardo's solution. I believe he had a better understanding of what was happening than I did and his solution should work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `not exists`:

```
select
   *
from
   system_users u
where
   not exists (
       select 
           1 
       from 
           system_user_permissions p 
       where 
           p.id = u.user 
           and p.permission in (2,3)
   )
```

All your original query is doing is negating any user that has *only* permission 2 or 3, not 1, 2, and 5 (which is what you want). A `not exists` will throw that user out as soon as a permission 2 or 3 is found in `system_user_permissions` for that user.

Comment: You're welcome! And for what it's worth, `exists` is also there, and it works conversely of `not exists`, so if you want to grab all users with permission 2 or 3, you would just take out the `not`, and voila, you got it.

Comment: My solution has the same approach, but this one is much more readable :)

Answer (score 1):

You could approach the opposite way, specifiying which users shouldn't appear in the list, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `u`.*
FROM (`system_users` AS u)
JOIN `system_user_permissions` AS p ON `u`.`id` = `p`.`user`
WHERE `p`.`user` NOT IN
  (SELECT DISTINCT `user`
   FROM `system_user_permissions`
   WHERE `permission` = 2 OR `permission` = 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the NOT IN keywords to select a group of values you do not want returned. Obviously, removing the "NOT" would have the opposite affect.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `u`.* 
FROM (`system_users` AS u) 
INNER JOIN `system_user_permissions` AS p 
   ON `u`.`id` = `p`.`user` 
WHERE `p`.`permission` not in (2,3)
```

Comment: Was really excited to try this, hadn't used not in before but still no luck. Still receiving 3900 as my count. If I select and output the permission id as well and list it out, I'm not getting that number outputted but it's just showing a different permission id that the user has

Comment: You need to include sample data of the tables for us. I'm not sure entirely what you mean by getting a different permission id.

Comment: @MattMoore - kilrizzy means he's getting rows with permissions of 1 or 5 or whatever, but that user still has a permission record with 2 or 3, so the user should be disqualified from the result set. Your query doesn't disqualify those users, just disqualifies the users with *only* the permissions 2 or 3.

Comment: @Eric.. oh I see. The user has multiple rows in the table with a different permission listed. So while the user may have permission 2, he also has permission 5 so is still included in the group when he shouldn' t be.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this? I think your problems is ()

SELECT DISTINCT `u`.*
FROM (`system_users` AS u)
JOIN `system_user_permissions` AS p ON `u`.`id` = `p`.`user`
WHERE (`p`.`permission` != 2 AND `p`.`permission` != 3 )